Why does the clear bookmarks option in ABAQUS fail?
I am using ABAQUS/CAE 2022. To import my model from a .inp file. I clicked File -? import Model, to make the task easier I set some bookmarks with the file directories. However, now that I want to clear old bookmarks so I clicked the clear bookmarks button.
However, everytime I close abaqus and re-open, the bookmarks I have clear already also re-appear. I have tried saving the cae and deleting the .gpr file to no avail.
